# Blank Gray screen After release app on play store

Tags: flutter

When the application is installed, it displays a blank gray screen.

[image]

Comment: Do you run 'flutter build ios' to create release build?

Comment: no, i run in debug & release mode work on smartphone me, but in release on play store after open app appear blank gray screen.

Comment: first of all run "flutter build ios" then open Runner.xcworkspace in your app’s ios folder  to config app version and build. https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios

Comment: I was just about to ask the same question. My (Android) app works perfectly on my emulator and on my physical device. But when generating a signed bundle and uploading it to the play store, all I get is the same gray area. I ran `adb logcat` and could not find anything that hints towards an error. If you have solved it by now, please tell me how.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your flutter project had errors. The errors which appear in the red screen(like something is null for example) during debug appear as a gray screen in production. I'd recommend you to debug the app.

[image]

Comment: I run in debug mode i dont have problem, but after i upload in playstore, app black grey screen